# What software is recommended for videos like these?

Tags: editing, software-recommendation, software

What software should I use for making the color grading like in this video and the slow motion.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to give you a pretty simple answer here.

ANY modern NLE will be able to do this. Your other option is shoot it all in camera and then just touch up a little in you NLE